# Join same table and get the max and min value of timestamp by id on separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've couldn't find a way of getting the min and max value of timestamp column for the same id by joining the same table and show the result on new row

For example

```
No | Name    | Date
1    John    01/01/2010
4    Chris   01/02/2009
1    John    01/01/2011
6    Alex    02/02/2010
1    Alex    01/01/2012
4    Norman  01/03/2012
6    Joshua  03/02/2012

I should somehow get :
No |   Name    | Date
1      John     01/01/2010
1      Alex     01/01/2012
4      Chris    01/02/2009
4      Norman    01/03/2012
6       Alex     01/01/2012
6      Joshua    03/02/2012
```

Comment: You don't have to join the same table. Group your rows by name and id. Then, find the max and min of `Date` column for each row.

Comment: I know how to get the values like that but I need to use JOIN for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the exact output you want:

```
select no, name, date
  from temp t
 where date = (select min(x.date) from temp x where x.no = t.no)
    or date = (select max(x.date) from temp x where x.no = t.no)
 order by no, date
```

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8243c/6/0

Edit - If you want to use JOIN:

```
select t.no, t.name, t.date
  from temp t
  join (select no, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
          from temp
         group by no) x
    on (t.no = x.no and t.date = min_date)
    or (t.no = x.no and t.date = max_date)
 order by t.no, t.date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8243c/19/0

(same output)

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple `MIN` and `MAX` do the job or there's more complex requirement?

```
SELECT no, name, MIN(date) as MinDate, MAX(date) as MaxDate
FROM temp t
GROUP BY no, name
ORDER BY no
```

demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8243c/3

Edit: could be done this way:

```
select t.no, name, mindate, maxdate
from temp t
left join (select min(date) as mindate, no
           from temp 
           group by no) t2 on t.no = t2.no
left join (select max(date) as maxdate, no
           from temp 
           group by no) t3 on t.no = t3.no
```

Comment: I know how to get the values like that but I need to use JOIN for learning purpose.

Comment: @user3341031 I gave you a response that uses JOIN above.

Comment: The query that uses the left join will not work. John comes back twice because he is on the table 3 times and he has the minimum date value for No 1. So he is listed twice for No 1 (as minimum).